# Convert SQL-Server specific INSERT query to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, sql-insert

I have a SQL Server 2008 specific query how can I execute same query in PostgreSQL.

```
INSERT INTO profile_answers_new (pro_ans_frn_pro_id, pro_ans_name)
SELECT pro_ans_frn_pro_id = @new_pro_id , pro_ans_name
FROM profile_answers_old WHERE profile_id = 1
```

How can I convert this query as a PostgreSQL specific one.

Comment: The only non-standard part is `pro_ans_frn_pro_id = @new_pro_id`. What's that supposed to do?

Comment: yes thats the only issue in this query , that parameter @new_pro_id is a variable that contains a value which is to be assigned in pro_ans_frn_pro_id column of profile_answers_old table and then is to be inserted into pro_ans_frn_pro_id.

Comment: And that could be just `select @new_pro_id, ...`. I can't see the purpose of the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

There are no variables in plain SQL in PostgreSQL. You can write a literal constant *as is* into the `SELECT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO profile_answers_new (pro_ans_frn_pro_id, pro_ans_name)
SELECT 1234, pro_ans_name     -- 1234 being @new_pro_id (integer)
FROM   profile_answers_old
WHERE  profile_id = 1
```

An expression like you have in your original statement (`pro_ans_frn_pro_id = @new_pro_id`) would be evaluated to `TRUE` / `FALSE` / `NULL`. You certainly don't want that.

If you wanted to hand in a parameter, you'd have to create a function like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(int)
  RETURNS void LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
INSERT INTO profile_answers_new (pro_ans_frn_pro_id, pro_ans_name)
SELECT $1, pro_ans_name
FROM   profile_answers_old
WHERE  profile_id = 1;
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT foo(1234);
```

But I doubt, that's what you want.

Comment: I am bounded to not to create function for this type of query , as my application consists of hundreds of queries like this.